# Visual Fortran Linker error obsolete _imp

Tags: linker, fortran, lnk2019

I get the following linker error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Console1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling with Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler 18.0.2.185 [IA-32]...
1>Console1.f90
1>Linking...
1>Console1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SETFLUIDSDLL referenced in function _MAIN__
1>Debug\Console1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
```

The source is

```
   program Console1

    implicit none

    INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE SETFLUIDSdll(hfld,ierr, hFld_length) 
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: SETFLUIDSdll
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE::hfld, ierr, hFld_length
    CHARaCTER(*) hfld
    INTEGER ierr, hFld_length
    END SUBROUTINE SETFLUIDSdll
    
    END INTERFACE 
    
    ! Variables
    CHARACTER (len = 40) :: hfld
    INTEGER ierr
    INTEGER hFld_length
    
    hfld = 'Test'
    
    ! Body of Console1
    print *, 'Hello World'

    call SETFLUIDSdll(hfld, ierr, hFld_length)
    
    end program Console1
```

I have a lib added containing the SETFLUIDSdll method. I do not know why the linker ist requiring a _imp__SETFLUIDSDLL. From where is the *imp* coming?

Comment: What happens when you remove the 2 lines with `!DEC$` ? Why do you use them in the first place? Can you show the complete link line, does it contain a reference to `dll`s / `lib`s?

Answer (score 2):

You also asked this in the [Intel support forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/LNK2019-error/td-p/1307808). The `__imp__` is generated by the compiler when you use a `DLLIMPORT` directive. When the DLL is linked, the export library, created by the linker, generates names with the same prefix. The purpose of this is to create a more efficient connection between the call and the DLL, saving a few instructions.

The reason you're getting the link error is that you have not linked to the export library (.LIB) generated when the DLL was linked. (Either that, or you failed to add `DLLEXPORT` directives for the procedure in the DLL.) The fix is to make sure that the DLL's export library is linked in with the executable.

Comment: SUBROUTINE SETFLUIDSdll(hfld,ierr) 
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL, ALIAS : '_SETFLUIDSdll@12' :: SETFLUIDSdll
    CHARaCTER(*) hfld
    INTEGER ierr
    END SUBROUTINE SETFLUIDSdll

works

Comment: I don't like your solution, it could lead to other errors. Replace the ALIAS with DECORATE, ALIAS:"SETFLUIDSdll". How did you end up with a (presumably) Fortran routine that has a mixed-case name? Also, with STDCALL your integer argument will be passed by value.